# Remove all columns to the right of a specific column

Tags: powerquery, m

I have an Excel template file with a dynamic number of columns that represent work week dates.  Some users have decided to add their own subtotal columns to the right of those columns.  I need a way to identify the first blank column, and then truncate that column and all columns following it.

I had previously been using the following script to remove all columns that begin with the word "Column":

```js
// Create a list of columns that start with "Column" and remove them.
Removed_ColumnNum_Columns = Table.RemoveColumns(PreviousStepName, List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(PreviousStepName), each Text.StartsWith(_, "Column") )),
```

Based on being able to find the first ColumnXX column, I want to remove it and all columns after it

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `List.PositionOf` to get your `ColumnIndex` instead of parsing text.

I'd put it together like this:

```
// [...]
ColumnList = Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"),
ColumnXX = List.Select(ColumnList, each Text.StartsWith(_, "Column")){0}, 
ColumnIndex = List.PositionOf(ColumnList, ColumnXX),
ColumnsToKeep = List.FirstN(ColumnList, ColumnIndex),
FinalTable = Table.SelectColumns(#"Promoted Headers", ColumnsToKeep)
```

Comment: Your answer is more robust than the one I proposed so I marked this as the accepted answer.

Comment: Can this be written as a single line or better yet a function?  I've been using this a lot.

Comment: Sure. You can abstract it out to a function.

Answer (score 0):

#### Remove Columns after ColumnXX

Find the first column that begins with the name "Column" and delete that column and all columns following it.   This parses the XX as the column index so you need to make sure you haven't deleted columns prior to this step.    i.e. "Column35" needs to be the 35th column at this step in the code.

```cpp
// Find the first ColumnXX column and remove it and all columns to the right. 
ColumnXX = List.Select(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"), each Text.StartsWith(_, "Column")){0}, 
ColumnIndex = Number.FromText(Text.Middle(ColumnXX, 6,4)), 
ColumnListToRemove = List.Range(Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"),ColumnIndex-1), 
RemovedTrailingColumns  = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Promoted Headers", ColumnListToRemove),
```

*To make this more robust I would prefer to have a way to identify the column index of columnXX without parsing the digits from it.*